# iPhone tab interface, should I hide tabs on 2+ levels deep?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm new to IOS development and I need some advice on when to hide main tabs.
I've been going through quite a few apps to figure out if there is a recommended approach, if the main tabs should be hidden or not once you are 2+ levels deep.

So my scenario is pretty standard, I have a tabbed interface aka "Apple Store" app.
Once I start navigating (pushing Controllers), should I hide the Tabs at the bottom and use only the NavigationBar?

Comment: From a design standpoint, there is no specific reason to show or hide the tabs, except where screen space must be maximized.  What do you want to show (i.e. a game, an image, a video, a file)?

Comment: The idea of using tabs is to allow the fast switching to different parts of the app in a easy way. If you want to hide the tab bar, it may be the case that you may not realy need a tab based app. Another useful functionality is the ability to pop to the rootViewController of one tab when you tap it while it's the active one.